# Convert HashMap which stores String[] to a new HashMap with only the String[0]

Tags: java, hashmap

this HashMap stores some String arrays:

```
HashMap<String, String[]> loaded_data = new HashMap();
```

I need to convert it to a new HashMap with all the same keys and value as String[0] like this

```
HashMap<String, String> trimmed_data = HashMap<String, String[0]> loaded_data;
```

Referring to JavaDocs here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html I have identified clone() and putAll() functions that might help with this but cannot think how.

Can someone help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would get all the mappings using [`entrySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29), and loop through them to take the first element of the array.

```
HashMap<String, String> trimmed_data = new HashMap<>();

for(Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : loaded_data.entrySet()){
   trimmed_data.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
    HashMap<String, String[]> loaded_data = new HashMap();
    HashMap<String, String> trimmed_data =new HashMap<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry:loaded_data.entrySet()){
        trimmed_data.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()[0]);
    }
```

You have to iterate though `loaded_data` map and take `oth` index element from it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getKeys()` to get all keys. The iterate over the keys get the value, `split()` the value get the 0th index of array that is returned from the `split()` function and store it in your new `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String[]> hm = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        hm.put("one", new String[] { "1", "2", "3" });
        hm.put("two", new String[] { "2", "3", "4" });
        hm.put("three", new String[] { "3", "4", "5" });

        Map<String, String> newHm = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Iterator it = hm.keySet().iterator(); // get iterator for keyset
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String str = (String) it.next();  
            newHm.put(str, hm.get(str)[0]);  // for each key , get value of [0]
        }

        System.out.println(newHm);
    }

O/P : {two=2, one=1, three=3}
```